# USB wireless Netgear adapter Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, wireless, netgear

My netgear wireless adapter appears to be the same model as from [this](/questions/568056/usb-wireless-netgear-adapter) thread, but the steps didn't end up working out for me. No errors were given. 
Note: This is the second attempt, so some files are already installed/updated. I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, I'm not used to the environment.

Here's the terminal after each step:

1. Note: I can't post more than 2 links, so I delete the http:// in front of the hits/gets.

   ```
   $ lsusb
   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0846:9011 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn [Broadcom BCM4323]

   $ sudo apt-get update 
   Hit:1 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
   Get:2 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [95.7 kB] 
   Hit:3 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease 
   Get:4 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB] 
   Fetched 190 kB in 1s (142 kB/s)
   Reading package lists... Done

   $ sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree    
   Reading state information... Done
   Note, selecting 'ndiswrapper' instead of 'ndiswrapper-common'
   ndiswrapper is already the newest version (1.59-6).
   ndiswrapper-utils-1.9 is already the newest version (1.59-6).
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 59 not upgraded.
   ```
2. Downloaded the files from post #6 and put them onto my desktop.

   ```
   $ arch
   x86_64
   $ cd ~/Desktop/Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2
   ```

   My command line now appears as:

   ```
   shawn@shawn-Z68XP-UD3P:~/Desktop/Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2$
   ```
3. As arch returned x84_64 I issued:

   ```
   $ sudo ndiswrapper -i bcmn43xx64.inf
   driver bcmn43xx64 is already installed

   $ sudo ndiswrapper -ma
   module configuration information is stored in /etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf
   ```
4. This step didn't return any information back.

   ```
   sudo depmod -a
   ```
5. This step also didn't return any information back.

   ```
   sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
   ```

Thanks for any help. I was going to pm Chili555, the author of the answer to the previous thread, but I couldn't find an option. (Maybe I need more rep?)

Edit 1:

```
$ dmesg | grep ndis
[25668.481615] rndis_host 5-2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:06:00.0-2, RNDIS device, 02:06:52:50:34:39
[25668.481640] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[25668.490912] rndis_host 5-2:1.0 enp6s0u2: renamed from usb0
```

with the correct adapter in:

```
$ dmesg | grep ndis
[25668.481615] rndis_host 5-2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:06:00.0-2, RNDIS device, 02:06:52:50:34:39
[25668.481640] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[25668.490912] rndis_host 5-2:1.0 enp6s0u2: renamed from usb0
[27435.290896] rndis_host 5-2:1.0 enp6s0u2: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:06:00.0-2, RNDIS device
[53404.308888] rndis_host 5-2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:06:00.0-2, RNDIS device, 02:06:52:50:34:39
[53404.321914] rndis_host 5-2:1.0 enp6s0u2: renamed from usb0
[53499.506118] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[53499.507750] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[53499.681200] ndiswrapper: driver bcmn43xx64 (,08/26/2009, 5.10.79.30) loaded
[53499.788872] rndis_host 5-2:1.0 enp6s0u2: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:06:00.0-2, RNDIS device
[53500.230542] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
[53500.236500] ndiswrapper 1-1.4:1.0 enxe0469a00acaa: renamed from wlan0
[53500.261564] ndiswrapper: interface renamed to 'enxe0469a00acaa'
[53522.657592] rndis_host 5-2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:06:00.0-2, RNDIS device, 02:06:52:50:34:39
[53522.676968] rndis_host 5-2:1.0 enp6s0u2: renamed from usb0
```

Comment: You can always PM me on ubuntuforums.org. However, let's crack the case right here. What is the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` and also: `dmesg | grep ndis` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: The terminal didn't return anything to me. Thanks for coming to the rescue. :D

Comment: The terminal didn't return anything to me for "sudo modprobe ndsiwrapper" The first time I ran it during step 10. Now I get "modprobe: FATAL: Module ndsiwrapper not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic" But I didn't redo all of the steps, do I need to? I edited dmesg grep ndis into the bottom of my main, also ran without redoing the steps. Gonna have to go to work in a few minutes.

Comment: I would try again: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ndiswrapper` and next:`sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-dkms` and finally: `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` Any errors, warnings, etc.?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot I had my other adapter installed (Was trying to get it to work after giving up on this one) I reran dmesg | grep ndis and got a entirely different result. ndis modprbe ndiswrapper didn't return anything. I'll put the dmesg into edit 2) up above.

Comment: I just did the three ndiswrapper commands and the modprobe didn't return anything. I redid all of the commands and ran dmesg | grep ndis, it has the same information as edit 2.

Comment: It looks quite good! If you detach the tether, does Network Manager see the Netgear? Does it see networks and try to connect?

Comment: Ah, well look that that. (lol) It takes 10-20 seconds after rebooting to appear when I'm not tethered, but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments reinstalling `ndiswrapper` and reperforming the steps following the installation fixed the issue. To reinstall `ndiswrapper`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ndiswrapper ndiswrapper-dkms
```

Comment: As you’re a reputation 6 user: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the “0” at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!